# How to count number of occurrences in a list in Dart?

Tags: dart

Why bellow code returns empty map, the code looks correct.

```
void main() {
  final List myList = [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'amber',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'orange',
    'red',
    'blue',
    'pink',
    'amber',
    'blue',
  ];

  final Map counts = {};

  myList.map((e) => counts.containsKey(e) ? counts[e]++ : counts[e] = 1);

  print(counts);
}
```

Comment: Also consider writing as: `var counts = <String, int>{}; for (var key in myList) counts.update(key, (count) => count + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is made clear with this adjustment to your example:

```dart
void main() {
  final List myList = [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'amber',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'orange',
    'red',
    'blue',
    'pink',
    'amber',
    'blue',
  ];

  var mapped = myList.map((e) => print('hello'));

  print(mapped.runtimeType);
}
```

You will observe that no "hello" is printed, and the return type of `map()` from the above call is `MappedListIterable<dynamic, void>` (at least it is when run today on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev)).

[Iterable.map()](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) returns a *lazy iterable*, described by the documentation:

> Returns a new lazy `Iterable` with elements that are created by calling `toElement` on each element of this `Iterable` in iteration order.

In other words, `map()` doesn't actually do anything, except return an `Iterable` which will, if used, do something.

As mentioned by others, there are some ways to achieve what you want.

1. Don't use `map()` for this purpose. Use a `for` loop instead.
2. Workaround by calling `.toList()` on the returned lazy iterable, which has the side-effect of evaluating the lazy iterable. However, as pointed out by @mmcdon20 in the comments, while this will work, it's not recommended, because it is unnecessarily wasteful.

Comment: Calling `.map(...).toList()` is not a good workaround, you are creating a pointless `List` object that serves no purpose. The appropriate method to call would be `.forEach(...)`, but in most cases I prefer a standard `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

**You forget toList();**

```
myList.map((e) => counts.containsKey(e) ? counts[e]++ : counts[e] = 1).toList();
```